# how do you add/remove markers on leaflet based on the buttons click on?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

i want to make a filter that would let users click on a button and only show markers on the leaflet map that relate to that button. (e.g if i clicked on ambulance button it would show only markers that have ambulances)

im making my criteria based off this json code(this is a snippet of it)

```
{
      "station_co_number":"801",
      "station_name":"HYATTSVILLE",
      "location_1":{
         "latitude":"38.96384532",
         "longitude":"-76.95262225",
         "human_address":"{\"address\": \"6200 BELCREST RD\", \"city\": \"Hyattsville\", \"state\": \"MD\", \"zip\": \"\"}"
      },
      "type":"VOLUNTEER",
      "medical_unit_onsite":"Y",
      "ambulance_onsite":"Y",
      "icon":"a8fbdc2c-f8f6-491a-b764-8d30aca84d5b",
      ":@computed_region_87xh_ddyp":"8789"
   },
```

i wanted to base it off the medical_unit_onsite value and the ambulance_onsite values. i wanted to make it so that if i clicked the ambulance button on my page, the leaflet would only show markers where the ambulance_onsite value is Y, the same could be said for the medical unit onsite. is there a way to do this? here is my current code

```
const mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([38.8447892, -76.8266697], 9);

            const attribution = 
            '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a>'

            const tileUrl = 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
            const tiles = L.tileLayer(tileUrl, { attribution })
            tiles.addTo(mymap)

            const url = 'https://data.princegeorgescountymd.gov/resource/bzf2-94qx.json';
            async function getData() {
              const response = await fetch(url)
              const data = await response.json();

              for (item of data) {
                let lat = item.location_1.latitude;
                let lng = item.location_1.longitude;
                let addy = item.human_address;
                let ambuLance = item.ambulance_onsite;
                let medicalOnsite = item.medical_unit_onsite;

                const marker = L.marker([lat, lng], title=item.station_name).addTo(mymap);

                const txt = `${item.station_name}`;
                marker.bindPopup(txt);
              }

            }
            $("#all").click(function() {
            map.addLayer(others)
            map.removeLayer(cafes)
        });
        $("#ambulance").click(function() {
          if(!ambulance == 'Y'){
            map.removeLayer(marker)
          }
            //map.addLayer(cafes)
            //map.removeLayer(others)
        });
        $("#medicalunit").click(function() {
          if(!medicalOnsite  == 'Y'){
            map.removeLayer(marker)

          }
            //map.addLayer(cafes)
            //map.addLayer(others)
        });

            getData();
```

im mainly trying to get my .click functions to work so that only markers where the value is "Y" are shown for each button that is pressed. greatly appreciated if you can help

here is the html too

```
<div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" id="all" class="btn btn-success">All</button>
            <button type="button" id="ambulance" class="btn btn-primary">Ambulance</button>
            <button type="button" id="medicalunit" class="btn btn-danger">Medical Unit</button>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 bg-light mt-5">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7">
              <h3>Selected Station Services Rating</h3>
                <!-- Might not need this block
                 <p> <b>Type: State</b></p>
                 <p> <b>Medical unit: Yes</b></p>
                  <p><b>Ambulance: Yes</b></p>
                  -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 pt-5">
             <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
             <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
             <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
             <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
             <i class="fa fa-star-half-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>

          </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>

leaflet javascript
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use featureGroups and add / remove them to the map.

```
var fgAmbulance = L.featureGroup();
var fgMedicalunit= L.featureGroup();
var fgOtherMarkers = L.featureGroup();

 async function getData() {
              const response = await fetch(url)
              const data = await response.json();

              for (item of data) {
                let lat = item.location_1.latitude;
                let lng = item.location_1.longitude;
                let addy = item.human_address;
                let ambuLance = item.ambulance_onsite;
                let medicalOnsite = item.medical_unit_onsite;

                const marker = L.marker([lat, lng], title=item.station_name);
                const txt = `${item.station_name}`;
                marker.bindPopup(txt);

                if(ambuLance == 'Y'){
                    fgAmbulance.addLayer(marker);
                }else if(medicalOnsite == 'Y'){
                    fgMedicalunit.addLayer(marker);
                }else{
                    fgOtherMarkers.addLayer(marker);
                }
              }
fgAmbulance.addTo(mymap);
fgMedicalunit.addTo(mymap);
fgOtherMarkers.addTo(mymap);
            }
```

```
$("#all").click(function() {
            mymap.addLayer(fgAmbulance);
            mymap.addLayer(fgMedicalunit);
            mymap.addLayer(fgOtherMarkers);
        });
        $("#ambulance").click(function() {
          mymap.addLayer(fgAmbulance);
          if(mymap.hasLayer(fgMedicalunit)){
              mymap.removeLayer(fgMedicalunit);
          }
          if(mymap.hasLayer(fgOtherMarkers)){
              mymap.removeLayer(fgOtherMarkers);
          }
        });
        $("#medicalunit").click(function() {
          mymap.addLayer(fgMedicalunit);
          if(mymap.hasLayer(fgAmbulance)){
              mymap.removeLayer(fgAmbulance);
          }
          if(mymap.hasLayer(fgOtherMarkers)){
              mymap.removeLayer(fgOtherMarkers);
          }
        });
```

This should be working

Comment: for the second part with the .click functions, do i include that in the getData function? or should it be its own thing?

Comment: so it should be separate from the getData function?